# How can I make the last child element of the details to be placed above the penultimate element?

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I use CSS to position a `<div>` element with the class **js-form-type-managed-file** above a `<table>` element?

I tried using `flexbox` and `order` but it didn't work.

```css
details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 1000px;
}

table {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  order: 2;
}

.js-form-type-managed-file {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary></summary>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <table class="responsive"></table>
  <div class="js-form-type-managed-file"></div>
</details>
```

Comment: Why can't you just reorder to components?

Comment: "Above" meaning "higher on the page, closer to the address bar"? Or does it mean "visually between the <table> and the viewer, so the <table> is obscured"? Also, I've brought the CSS from linked demo into the question, next time please do this yourself as your "*[mcve]*" code must be in the question, further without content (even dummy, simple content) it's hard to visualise what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: flex` has no effect on the `details` element. So, the `order` property is useless, as flex properties are not in effect.

Either use JavaScript (if you can't change the mark-up) or wrap the items inside `details` in a container, then use flex.

```css
details {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 1000px;
}

[nested] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

table {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  order: 1;
}

.js-form-type-managed-file {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary></summary>
  <div nested>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <table class="responsive"></table>
    <div class="js-form-type-managed-file"></div>
  </div>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

The details component does not allow you to do this.

You should wrap the 2 divs like this:

```
  <details>
    <summary></summary>
    <div></div> 
    <div></div>
    <div class="flexParent">
      <table class="responsive"></table>
      <div class="js-form-type-managed-file"></div>
    </div>
  </details>
```

Then use this CSS:

```
 .flexParent {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   width: 1500px;
   height: 1000px;
 }
 
 table {
   width: 1200px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
   order: 2;
 }
 
 .js-form-type-managed-file {
   width: 1200px;
   height: 100px;
   background: yellow;
   order: 1;
 }
```

Comment: I can't change the markup because it's generated by my CMS. I can only change it using CSS.